# the command of !date cannot run from jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I was trying to using `!date` to print date-related information in jupyter notebook, but it seems that it just hang around there without running, what might be reason. I am using Anaconda virtual environment on windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IPython syntax, the exclamation mark (!) allows users to run shell commands from inside a Jupyter Notebook code cell.

If you are on Windows, **date** will show the system data and allows you  to set a new one. This doesn't make much sense from inside Jupyter Notebooks.

If you want to see the current date and time in IPython, instead use

```
import time
time.strftime("%c")
```